# Bootstrap: center the title on the navbar and move logout button right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the navbar, how can I center the title "My project" and keep the logout button on the right of the same line as the title:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div>
        <h1>My Project</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="post" action="{{url_for("logout")}}">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user white"></i>
        <font style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:10px;padding-right:5px;">{{ g.user.get_name() }}</font>
        <button id="logout" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Logout</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <h1 align="center"><div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="post" action="{{url_for("logout")}}">My Project
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user white"></i>
                    <font style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:10px;padding-right:5px;">{{ g.user.get_name() }}</font>
                    <input id="logout" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Logout">
                </form>
            </div></h1>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Longest `<h1>` you've ever seen)))))

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">  <div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header" style="float: center;">
    <form class="navbar-form " method="post" action="{{url_for("logout")}}">
      <div align="center" >

    <h1 > My Project  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user white"></i> </h1>

    <font style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:10px;padding-right:5px;">{{ g.user.get_name() }}</font>
      <p class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" >

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <p class="navbar-right"><button id="logout" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Logout</button>
  </p>
  </ul>
</p>
      </div>

    </form>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ySX3q/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via simple css

```
<style>
.container {
    position:relative;  
}
.navbar-collapse {
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;    
}
</style>
```